# Cross-Subdomain Post/get Request with PHP Sessions

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

I have a page m.mydomain.com/login.php (http/80) page using jquery.ajaxForm posting/getting to auth.mydomain.com/login.php (https/443)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: m.mydomain.com');
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.mydomain.com');
session_start();

/**Login and db stuff there*/
if($allowed)
{
   $_SESSION['check_login'] = true;
   print 1;
}
else
{
   print 0;
}
```

So in login.php i get a result of the ajax call "1", but on accessing $_SESSION I get an empty array.

Code:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.mydomain.com');
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);
```

Calling auth.mydomain.com/login.php (https/443) regulary in browser (with GET request) results in being logged in on m.mydomain.com/login.php (http/80)

Comment: Are the domain and sub domain running on the same server? Also make sure that the PHP session cookie name is the same for each.

Comment: Yes domain and subdomain run on the same server. I just set manually a session cookie name and I can read that there is a cookie available to read but $_SESSION is empty

Comment: Are the requests via ajax? If so you need to make sure `withcredentials` is set to `true` in the `xhr` object.

Comment: Thanak you that made the trick

Comment: I will add it as an answer then so you can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When preforming the request via ajax, you need to make sure `withcredentials` is set to `true` in the `xhr` object so that cookies are sent with the request.